# HTML string as context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working with AJAX, I encountered the following problem:
http://jsbin.com/iriquf/1

`data` variable is a basic representation of HTML string.

AJAX returns similar string, but with whitespaces (usually).

So, I tried to look up `<h1 />` inside the retrieved AJAX data, but, without dummy element I couldn't manage to do it.

Is there a better way than wrapping the string into a dummy element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead

```
$(data).eq(0).text()
```

since `$(data)` is a jQuery wrapped collection returning `[h1, h2, p, div]` you can address the `h1` element with `$(data).eq(0)`

example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/iriquf/3/edit

Otherwise if you don't know the index of `<h1>` element in your collection, make a simple loop to find it

```
  $(data).each(function(i, node) {
    if (node.nodeName === 'H1') {
       console.log($(this).text()); 
    }
  });
```

(but I strongly prefer the dummy wrapper to this method)

Comment: Yes, but not always I will be looking for the first element in collection.

Comment: instead of using `.eq` you could use `.find` with the selector for the element that you are looking for e.g. `$(data).find('h1:first')`

Comment: @Nalum, I've tested it, doesn't work. And, I guess, I'll be sticking to dummy element.

Comment: Sorry about that. Was in a bit of a rush so didn't test it. Shouldn't have made the comment while in a rush though.